# problems using slime on emacs24

Tags: emacs, configuration, lisp

I install slime through ELPA. Here is what my .emacs file looks like:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl --noinform")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/slime/") 
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

I get the following error when I start emacs:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `/home/name/.emacs':
>
> File error: Cannot open load file, slime
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

When I debug:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "slime")
  require(slime)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/name/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 91
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/name/.emacs" "/home/name/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

When I visit ~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20130308.1112, slime.el is clearly there. Other people online seem to be having issues too. If I cannot get it to work with emacs24, how can I setup a slime environment for common lisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed emacs 24 using the Debian amd64 package from Damien Cassou's ppa. I had some problems with slime (I don't recall if they were the same as those above). I fixed it by reinstalling quicklisp (http://www.quicklisp.org/), then using it to install slime:

```
(ql:quickload :quicklisp-slime-helper)
```

It works fine with sbcl for me (on two machines). I just looked at my .emacs; I have nothing added to my load-path, just

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I've just noted that you load path says `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/slime/")` but your slime.el file is at `~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20130308.1112` so in a different location. You probably have to correct it for: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20130308.1112/")`
2. You have not said (--noinform) where is your sbcl `(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl --noinform")`. So that I guess you have to do, at command line: `$ which sbcl` then the system will say to you where sbcl is (probably /usr/bin/sbcl) and inform it to emacs by `(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/sbcl")`